# vue slots and HTML from objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some data in my vue component that looks like this,

```
items: [
        {
          slug: 'this-is-title-1',
          title: 'This is title 1',
          content:
            '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut et diam quis sem mollis viverra quis sed arcu. Nulla id nulla mollis tortor eleifend aliquam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Suspendisse quam ipsum, egestas sed lacus a, egestas pretium lorem. Nam non metus quis nulla porta porttitor. Etiam fringilla lorem sed sem dapibus cursus. Maecenas commodo lorem lorem, eu mollis urna aliquam vitae. Vestibulum sit amet ligula a risus dignissim elementum. Nunc volutpat turpis diam, eu lacinia sapien commodo in. Nulla euismod lorem non sapien pharetra consequat. Sed cursus vehicula molestie. Ut a tristique est.</p>'
        },
        {
          slug: 'this-is-title-2',
          title: 'This is title 2',
          content:
            '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut et diam quis sem mollis viverra quis sed arcu. Nulla id nulla mollis tortor eleifend aliquam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Suspendisse quam ipsum, egestas sed lacus a, egestas pretium lorem. Nam non metus quis nulla porta porttitor. Etiam fringilla lorem sed sem dapibus cursus. Maecenas commodo lorem lorem, eu mollis urna aliquam vitae. Vestibulum sit amet ligula a risus dignissim elementum. Nunc volutpat turpis diam, eu lacinia sapien commodo in. Nulla euismod lorem non sapien pharetra consequat. Sed cursus vehicula molestie. Ut a tristique est.</p>'
        },
      ],
```

I am looping over the data in inserting the content attribute into a slot, like so,

```
<template #content>
    {{ item.content }}
</template>
```

This is getting rendered out as just a string not has HTML is there something I can do to make my slot parse HTML? I assumed I wouldn't no have to use `v-html` which I would still prefer not to do due to the content coming from a CMS and xss risks.

Comment: you still need to render the HTML if you want HTML, so in the end you have to use v-html or render component which uses the content as a template etc, if you are worried about xss then don't use HTML at all, instead use markdown then render to HTML from the markdown, also all cms's are kind of open to xss if you add it, that's kind of the point is to allow HTML to be rendered, prevent attackers adding content and then it won't matter

Comment: Sorry, v-html is the only way out.